# storage issue in cache

Tags: asp.net, caching

I ahve implemented brute force protection via limitation of failed login counts as here: http://madskristensen.net/post/Brute-force-protect-your-website.aspx
But i'm encountering two issues:

- After certain amount of time ( in my case 2 minutes) record in cache is not expired and i'm unable to log in again. This means that when function checks the number of failed attempts, it still gets maximum allowed after this 5 minutes
- cache from MSDN as I understood is single storage for application. From what i see in my application, it seems like cache is per application per IP. Why?
  Any suggestions? Here's my code:

  ```
  int CountOfFailedLoginAttempts()
  {
     if(Cache["L1|"+TextBox1.Text]==null)
     {
         return 0;
     }
     return (int) Cache["L1|" + TextBox1.Text];

  }
  void AddFailedAttempt()
  {
      if(Cache["L1|"+TextBox1.Text]==null)
      {
          Cache.Insert("L1|"+TextBox1.Text,1,null,System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,new TimeSpan(0,2,0));
      }
      else
      {
          int tries = (int) Cache["L1|" + TextBox1.Text];
          Cache["L1|" + TextBox1.Text] = tries + 1;
      }
  }
  void ClearFailedAttemptCounter()
  {
      Cache.Remove("L1|" + TextBox1.Text);
  }
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (CountOfFailedLoginAttempts() >= 5)
      {
          Label1.Text = "Login will be unavailable for 2 minutes";
      }
      else
      {
          SqlConnection con =
              new SqlConnection("valid connection string");
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select top 1 password from users WHERE UserName=@UN", con);
          cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UN", TextBox1.Text));
          con.Open();
          string res = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
          con.Close();
          if (res == TextBox2.Text)
          {
              FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBox1.Text, true);
              ClearFailedAttemptCounter();
          }
          else
          {
              Label1.Text = "Wrong password. "+(5-CountOfFailedLoginAttempts()).ToString()+"more attempts and access will be suspended for 2 minutes.";
              AddFailedAttempt();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: You've pasted your connection string password. Now, go and change it.

Comment: changed, thank you. Also I know that passwords in my DB are not hashed. But that will be changed of cause too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers. As it turned out, the problem is in this line:

```
Cache["L1|" + TextBox1.Text] = tries + 1;
```

The mechanism is quite diffrent than i thought. Instead of replacing the value, it is removing the value of specified key in cache, and inserting new one, **BUT** with no expiration settings. Because of that it seemed like value never expires. That is relevant for both Absolute and Sliding expiry modes. I have solved problem like that:

```
void AddFailedAttempt()
    {
        if(Cache["L1|"+TextBox1.Text]==null)
        {
            Cache.Insert("L1|"+TextBox1.Text,1,null,System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        }
        else
        {
            int tries = (int) Cache["L1|" + TextBox1.Text];
            Cache.Remove("L1" + TextBox1.Text);
            Cache.Insert("L1|" + TextBox1.Text, tries+1, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        }
    }
```

And in that way everything works properly.

Answer (score 2):

You're using sliding expiration (of 2 minutes), which means that your cache item will remain while someone is still reading the value within that time. This means that your account will be blocked forever if you keep retrying every minute.

The cache is a cache, not a critical data storage. You can not count on items remaining for two full minutes, memory pressure at the server may force ASP.NET to evict items from the cache. There's also possibilities of web farms/gardens that will give you several worker processes (perhaps spread over several machine) which will all have their own cache.

Comment: but the problem is that even if item is not read from cache, the same issue occurs. Could you tell me better way?